# Why does my code keep crashing when trying to setup my collide system?

Tags: python

So I'm making a small game with painter for a school final and I got to where my collision part and for some reason, it just crashes. Also, I'm using visual studio code. I was also wondering if there was a way to condense most of this code. I feel as though I am doing it the longest way possible. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
import turtle as trtl

#tutle config
wn = trtl.Screen()
field = trtl.Turtle()
line = trtl.Turtle()

#feild setup
area = 0
line.speed(0)
yard = 0


#make field border
field.shape("square")
field.color("green")
field.shapesize(100)

#line setup
line.hideturtle()
line.color("white")
line.pensize(10)
line.penup()
line.goto(-700,-310)
line.pendown()
while(yard != 10):
    line.left(90)
    line.forward(620)
    line.penup()
    line.right(90)
    line.forward(70)
    line.pendown()
    line.right(90)
    line.forward(620)
    line.left(90)
    line.penup()
    line.forward(70)
    line.pendown()
    yard += 1
line.left(90)
line.forward(620)


#make sideline   
line.penup()
line.goto(-800,-310)
line.pendown()
line.right(90)
line.forward(1600)
line.left(90)
line.forward(620)
line.left(90)
line.forward(1600)
line.left(90)
line.forward(620)

#make endzone
line.fillcolor("black")
line.begin_fill()
line.left(90)
line.forward(90)
line.left(90)
line.forward(620)
line.left(90)
line.forward(90)
line.left(90)
line.forward(620)
line.end_fill()
line.penup()
line.goto(710,-310)
line.pendown()
line.begin_fill()
line.left(90)
line.forward(90)
line.left(90)
line.forward(620)
line.left(90)
line.forward(90)
line.left(90)
line.forward(620)
line.end_fill()

#game setup

#turtle config
player = trtl.Turtle()

#player setup
player.penup()
player.shape("circle")
player.color("gold")
player.goto(710,0)

#make player controls
def move_left():
    player.setheading(180)
    player.forward(2)
    wn.delay(1)
def move_right():
    player.setheading(0)
    player.forward(2)
    wn.delay(1)
def move_up():
    player.setheading(90)
    player.forward(2)
    wn.delay(1)
def move_down():
    player.setheading(270)    
    player.forward(2)
    wn.delay(1)







#setup enemy

enemy_1 = trtl.Turtle()
enemy_2 = trtl.Turtle()
enemy_3 = trtl.Turtle()
enemy_4 = trtl.Turtle()
enemy_5 = trtl.Turtle()
enemy_6 = trtl.Turtle()



enemy_1.penup()
enemy_1.shape("circle")
enemy_1.color("red")
enemy_1.goto(0,0)

enemy_2.penup()
enemy_2.shape("circle")
enemy_2.color("red")
enemy_2.goto(210,0)

enemy_6.penup()
enemy_6.shape("circle")
enemy_6.color("red")
enemy_6.goto(420,0)

enemy_3.penup()
enemy_3.shape("circle")
enemy_3.color("red")
enemy_3.goto(-210,0)

enemy_4.penup()
enemy_4.shape("circle")
enemy_4.color("red")
enemy_4.goto(-420,0)

enemy_5.penup()
enemy_5.shape("circle")
enemy_5.color("red")
enemy_5.goto(-630,0)


#stop
def stop():
    wn.bye()

#collide
def is_collided_with1(a, b):
    return abs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) < 10 and abs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) < 10
def is_collided_with2(a, b):
    return abs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) < 10 and abs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) < 10
def is_collided_with3(a, b):
    return abs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) < 10 and abs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) < 10
def is_collided_with4(a, b):
    return abs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) < 10 and abs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) < 10
def is_collided_with5(a, b):
    return abs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) < 10 and abs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) < 10
def is_collided_with6(a, b):
    return abs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) < 10 and abs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) < 10



#follow
def follow_1():
    enemy_1.setheading(enemy_1.towards(player))
    enemy_1.forward(2)
    if is_collided_with1(enemy_1, player):
        stop()
    else:
        wn.ontimer(follow_1, 10)

def follow_2():
    enemy_2.setheading(enemy_2.towards(player))
    enemy_2.forward(2)
    wn.ontimer(follow_2, 10)
    if is_collided_with2(enemy_2, player):
        stop()
    else:
        wn.ontimer(follow_2, 10)

def follow_3():
    enemy_3.setheading(enemy_3.towards(player))
    enemy_3.forward(2)
    wn.ontimer(follow_3, 10)
    if is_collided_with3(enemy_3, player):
        stop()
    else:
        wn.ontimer(follow_3, 10)

def follow_4():
    enemy_4.setheading(enemy_4.towards(player))
    enemy_4.forward(2)
    wn.ontimer(follow_4, 10)
    if is_collided_with4(enemy_4, player):
        stop()
    else:
        wn.ontimer(follow_4, 10)

def follow_5():
    enemy_5.setheading(enemy_5.towards(player))
    enemy_5.forward(2)
    wn.ontimer(follow_5, 10)
    if is_collided_with5(enemy_5, player):
        stop()
    else:
        wn.ontimer(follow_5, 10)

def follow_6():
    enemy_6.setheading(enemy_6.towards(player))
    enemy_6.forward(2)
    wn.ontimer(follow_6, 10)
    if is_collided_with6(enemy_6, player):
        stop()
    else:
        wn.ontimer(follow_6, 10)








#setup out of bounds







 

#mainloop

wn.onkeypress(move_left,"Left")
wn.onkeypress(move_down,"Down")
wn.onkeypress(move_right,"Right")
wn.onkeypress(move_up,"Up")

wn.listen()

follow_1()
follow_2()
follow_3()
follow_4()
follow_5()
follow_6()



wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does it crashes with any particular error written on console?

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your script on my machine and I had some problems with a couple things, but without knowing the precise error you get on your side, I'm not sure this will solve your problems.

Firt of all, the player location goes out of my screen, so I changed it to

```
player.goto(250,250)
```

Then, moving the player continuosly causes a crash caused by max recursion reached and it looks like you can't set the heading continuosly at each key press.. so you could change your movements to something like this:

```
def move_left():
    if player.heading() != 180:
        player.setheading(180)
    player.forward(2)

def move_right():
    if player.heading() != 0:
        player.setheading(0)
    player.forward(2)

def move_up():
    if player.heading() != 90:
        player.setheading(90)
    player.forward(2)

def move_down():
    if player.heading() != 270:
        player.setheading(270)    
    player.forward(2)
```

This seems to work on my computer, at least the game does not crash until the collision with the enemies happen. There are probably other problems, such as enemies not always moving but I'm no turtle expert so I have no idea what is wrong on that side.

As a side note to write less code, some functions do the same things, you need only one is_collided_with, not multiple which do the same things and so on.

Comment: Yeah, I also noticed the problem of the turtles not moving. At first, I added a delay to the player's movement controls and that fixed the problem. After I added the collision system it started to do that again. Also, the game is supposed to close after a collision, I added that to make telling if the collision worked easier. Thanks for the help!

Comment: also if you add
'wn.setup(width=1600, height=620)' 
to the code your screen should be fixed